# Why is the Op.not operator no longer working in Sequelize 4.41.0?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, where-clause, operator-keyword, not-operator

I recently upgraded many of the packages in my project, and since I did, the following query now fails:

```
query['where'] = { [Op.and]: [
        sequelize.where(Database.getInstance().getConnection().col('id'), '!=', jsonObject['id'] ),
        sequelize.where(Database.getInstance().getConnection().col('username'), jsonObject['username'])
]};
console.log('Check if username is unique...');
console.log(query);
```

It results in:

```
 Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value Where {
   attribute: Col { col: 'id' },
   comparator: '=',
   logic: { [Symbol(not)]: 1563 } }
   attribute: Col { col: 'id' },
```

I also tried:

```
query['where'] = { [Op.and]: [
    sequelize.where(Database.getInstance().getConnection().col('id'), '!=', jsonObject['id'] ),
    sequelize.where(Database.getInstance().getConnection().col('username'), jsonObject['username'])
]};
```

[While following the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-where), but it still resulted in an error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value Where { attribute: Col { col: 'id' }, comparator: '!=', logic: 1563 }
```